# Connecting to php mysql database using Ember.js

Tags: php, ember.js

I have been learning PHP and codeigniter for a year or so now.

However, I am intrigued at what a JS framework can do.  I would prefer not to start over in Ruby, though.

I have looked around, but simply can't find enough information on how ember.js or a similar framework works with the backend.

So, assuming I have created a template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="posts">
<div class='posts'>
{{#each model}}
    <h3>{{title}}</h3>
    <p> {{desc}} </p>
{{/each}}
</div>
</script>
```

and a model

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
   id: DS.attr('string'),
   title: DS.attr('string'),
   desc: DS.attr('string')
});
```

How do I get JSON information from a URL?  Assuming: `http://mypage/ajax/getpostjson/postdata'` will return a JSON string with id/title/desc?

The ember.js docs have something like the following:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  url: 'http://mypage/ajax/getpostjson/postdata'
});
```

Although I am not sure how you are supposed to call this data or where its stored, or specifically, how youre supposed to use it or set up your app.

In other tutorials, I found this:

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
       return App.Post.find();
   } 
});
```

Which I assume connects to `App.Post.` though I still am very confused.

I am just hoping to get pointed in the right direction through simple examples.

Comment: A good point to get started aside from the official ember.js docs and reading trough the source code is http://emberwatch.com/ this answer is maybe also of interest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641713/using-embedding-ember-js-with-in-codeigniter

Comment: "How do I get JSON information from a URL?" - you would create an API (using whatever language, PHP, Ruby, anything...) that matches URL's that ember's data-adapter will request then use your server-side language to access the db and return your objects as JSON.